# How to compare two OpenAPI 3.x YAML files?

Tags: yaml, diff, openapi

I am trying to find a way to compare 2 OpenAPI 3.x YAML files, each representing an API, so I want to know if the 2 files document the same API. Any idea what approach to start with?

Answer (score 1):

[openapi-diff](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-diff) lets you compare two OpenAPI 3.x files and export the diff as text, Markdown, or HTML.

```
openapi-diff api1.yaml api2.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the file type, you might want to use a file compare tool such as Winmerge
https://winmerge.org/?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

To compare local files with docker:

```
docker run --rm -t -v $(pwd)/data:/data:ro tufin/oasdiff -base /data/openapi-test1.yaml -revision /data/openapi-test3.yaml
```

If the files are accessible over http:

```
docker run --rm -t tufin/oasdiff -format yaml -base https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Tufin/oasdiff/main/data/openapi-test1.yaml -revision https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Tufin/oasdiff/main/data/openapi-test3.yaml
```

Or, use it as a service:

```
curl -X POST -F base=@spec1.yaml -F revision=@spec2.yaml https://api.oasdiff.com/diff
```

For additional info about OpenAPI diff and breaking changes see:
https://github.com/Tufin/oasdiff